# Finding the area of intersection when a polygon is intersected by infinite number of polygon.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Lets say that I have a polygon (let's call it "origin shape").Is there a way (something like a formula) to find the area of intersection if this origin shape is intersected by $n$ number of polygons.

For Example:
Let's say that my origin shape is a square and  $n = 4$, So it is being intersected by 4 different polygons. Then how can I find the area which is shaded in orange in the figure below:

[image]

Now in this example my origin shape was a square but what if it is something like a 7 sided polygon or what if my origin shape is not a polygon (circle). I mean is there something like a general formula for something like this. Some resources regarding problems like this would be very helpful for me. Thnx

Comment: You problem statement is too broad. I doubt there is a general solution.

Comment: @Vasya Even when the origin shape is the same as intersecting shapes?